# I want to know why setState does not work in onSubmit function

Tags: reactjs, function

I wanted to let users make alarm lists.
However, in Form component, setAlarmLists does not work properly in onSubmit function.
I wanted to check If I wrote some code wrong so I did console.log to check variable 'concated',
it came out nothing wrong.

I want to know why setState function not works here :( !!

```
let [AlarmLists,setAlarmLists]=useState([]);

return(
    <div className='content'>
        Now {now}
        <div id='lists'>Alarm lists</div>
        <AlarmList setAlarmLists={setAlarmLists} AlarmLists={AlarmLists}></AlarmList>
        {openForm?<FORM setAlarmLists={setAlarmLists} AlarmLists={AlarmLists}></FORM>:null}
        <div><button className='buttons' onClick={()=>{setOpenForm(!openForm)}}>{plusorMinus} 
    </button></div>       
        
    </div>
   )
}

function FORM({setAlarmLists,AlarmLists}){
   let id=useRef(0);
   
   function AddAlarmlist(hour,min){
       let list={
           id: id.current,
           hour:hour,
           min:min
        };
    console.log(list);
    let concated=AlarmLists.concat(list);
    console.log(concated);
    id++;  
    return concated;
      
}

return(
    <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target[0].value,e.target[1].value);
        setAlarmLists(AddAlarmlist(e.target[0].value,e.target[1].value));
        console.log(AlarmLists);
        }}>
        <input type="text"></input>
    Hour   
    <input type="text"></input>
    Min
    <button>Set Alarm</button>
    </form>
     )
 }

function AlarmList({AlarmLists}){
   AlarmLists.map((alarm,i)=>{
        return(
          <div>
              {alarm[i].hour}:{alarm[i].min}
          </div>
      )
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on submit is working absolutely fine. Try updating following code:

```
function AlarmList({ AlarmLists }) {
  return AlarmLists.map((alarm, i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {alarm.hour}:{alarm.min}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Firstly you are not returning your data from the `AlarmList` component. Secondly, you are not accessing the `AlarmLists` data properly.